# mismatched input ')' expecting END

Tags: apache-pig

I need to create DMS_EPRPFL entity as shown by this pig script :

```
DMS_EPRPFL = FOREACH ORDER_EPSE_ENEE_ENR  GENERATE

GROUP_EPSE_ENEE_ENR::IDT_GCP           AS    IDT_GCP,
GROUP_EPSE_ENEE_ENR::CD_FRM_JUR        AS    CD_FRM_JUR,
GROUP_EPSE_ENEE_ENR::DA_CRE_EPS        AS    DA_CRE_EPS,
GROUP_EPSE_ENEE_ENR::NO_SIREN           AS   NO_SIREN,
GROUP_EPSE_ENEE_ENR::CD_POST            AS   CD_POST,
GROUP_EPSE_ENEE_ENR::CD_OSCE_PAYS_FIS    AS  CD_OSCE_PAYS_FIS,
GROUP_EPSE_ENEE_ENR::CD_NAF              AS  CD_NAF,
GROUP_EPSE_ENEE_ENR::CD_NACE             AS  CD_NACE,
(CASE (GROUP_EPSE_ENEE_ENR::CD_AXE_MCH)
WHEN ('PLIB' OR 'ATPE' OR 'COMM') THEN 'P'
WHEN ('PME') THEN 'E'
WHEN ('AGRI') THEN 'A'
WHEN ('OBNL') THEN 'O'
WHEN ('COLL') THEN 'C'
WHEN ('EFIN') THEN 'B'
WHEN ('NONA' OR 'SCI') THEN 'X')               AS CD_MARCHE,
GROUP_EPSE_ENEE_ENR::CD_AXE_SNIV_MCH           AS CD_AXE_SNIV_MCH,
MIN(GROUP_EPSE_ENEE_ENR::A_PRM_CTR)            AS A_PRM_CTR,
MIN(GROUP_EPSE_ENEE_ENR::A_PRM_CAV)            AS A_PRM_CAV,
MIN(GROUP_EPSE_ENEE_ENR::A_PRPRE)              AS A_PRPRE,
GROUP_EPSE_ENEE_ENR::CD_NOT                    AS CD_NOT;
```

The problem is about `CD_MARCHE` .In fact I need to generate it according to specific conditions and using the case operator.

When executing the script I have this error :

> mismatched input ')' expecting END

in this line

```
 WHEN ('NONA' OR 'SCI') THEN 'X')               AS CD_MARCHE,
```

I can't find the problem there.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

From 
http://pig.apache.org/docs/latest/basic.html#arithmetic

CASE either takes

```
CASE expression [ WHEN value THEN value ]+ [ ELSE value ]? END
```

OR

```
CASE [ WHEN condition THEN value ]+ [ ELSE value ]? END
```

In your example, you're using the former but mixing condition (A OR B) where it only accepts value.   Two changes needed.

Add "END" at the end of your case statement and use the latter CASE statement.

Rewrite

```
(CASE (field)
    WHEN ( 'PLIB' OR 'ATPE' OR 'COMM' ) THEN 'P' 
    WHEN ('PME') THEN 'E'
    ...
    WHEN ('NONA' OR 'SCI') THEN 'X') AS CD_MARCHE,
```

to

```
(CASE 
    WHEN (field in ('PLIB','ATPE','COMM') ) THEN 'P' 
    WHEN (field == 'PME') THEN 'E'
    ...
    WHEN (field in ('NONA','SCI')) THEN 'X' END) AS CD_MARCHE,
```

Comment: thank you for your respons but it appears this errors ` Pig script failed to parse: NoViableAltException(59@[])`

Comment: Hmm. Are you sure you're using the 2nd CASE format and not the 1st ?   Just adding "END" can give you that error but moving to 2nd CASE format should work.  I can take a look if you can share your updated script.